# Unwanted White Spacing Between Divs in CSS/html

Tags: html, css, margins

Can someone explain why there is white space between the `#main_content` (the 3 columns) and `#footer`?

There is also also white space above `#main_content`

Also, the `<p>` text does not align.

I have tried to add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` to the different `divs` but it doesn't seem to work.  Hoping someone can shed some light on the matter.  thank you!

```css
#main_content{
 width:960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

#left_content{
 background-color: red;
 width:280px;
 min-height: 350px;
 float: left;
}

#middle_content{
 background-color: orange;
 margin-left:280px;
 margin-right:280px;
 min-height: 350px;
}

#right_content{
 background-color: green;
 width:280px;
 float:right;
 min-height: 350px;
}

#footer{
 min-height: 100px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="testcss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="main_content">
  <div id="left_content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exercitation lorem wisi non, vitae dolor, ipsum interdum nam sociosqu quis rutrum, qui enim vel mattis proin nulla. Rutrum arcu viverra vestibulum in quisque nullam, et vivamus, ut malesuada in. Arcu dolor in magna pede, turpis mauris, erat sed enim metus wisi vestibulum, molestie rhoncus, nunc at sed taciti eu et. Duis nibh porta purus, donec posuere vestibulum sit, magna sit elementum, aenean volutpat</p>
</div>

 <div id="right_content">
   <p>Sociis vel magna nec, lorem magna duis. Nulla at ut vel, corrupti non ridiculus pellentesque dapibus iaculis. Nibh ultricies mollis eget sodales inceptos odio, nonummy auctor enim pellentesque. Quis arcu amet. Accumsan morbi nec risus, scelerisque nec amet semper duis purus class, cras amet vel eu praesent mauris, velit nisl vestibulum interdum turpis neque fermentum, sollicitudin nulla amet adipiscing non et et. Volutpat erat.</p>
</div>

 <div id="middle_content" >
   <p>nec dignissimos magna wisi vitae. Quis auctor sapien suspendisse enim leo ac, quisque aliquet velit quis inceptos, sed quisque mattis eget lectus laoreet, est sagittis eu elementum rutrum. Elit fusce sodales aliquet et diam placerat, porttitor imperdiet praesent at id, nascetur suscipit, nisl et nulla. Ac at urna maecenas, vitae ullamcorper nunc aliquam, viverra habitasse id etiam aliquam. In dolores, accumsan nec ligula dolor felis.</p>
</div>

 <div id="footer">
   <p>nec dignissimos magna wisi vitae. Quis auctor sapien suspendisse enim leo ac, quisque aliquet velit quis inceptos, sed quisque mattis eget lectus laoreet, est sagittis eu elementum rutrum. Elit fusce sodales aliquet et diam placerat, porttitor imperdiet praesent at id, nascetur suscipit, nisl et nulla. Ac at urna maecenas, vitae ullamcorper nunc aliquam, viverra habitasse id etiam aliquam. In dolores, accumsan nec ligula dolor felis.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `p` has a default `margin`. You have to remove it (`#footer p { margin: 0; }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers define a default margin (usually 8px) for the body element - that's why you have space at the top. Paragraphs also have a default margin, which could be removed with css. For example:

You could reset the margin and padding of all elements to zero:

```
* {
   margin: 0;  
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Or you could be more specific:

```
body { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}

p { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is there's top/bottom margin on p element, so just add:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```